# No such method Error

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to build a google app engine application using java and eclipse which makes use of an external library.
I have been having some issues with serializing a particular class which I need to save, so I downloaded the source for the library and added it as its own project in eclipse and linked the project I'm working on to it as well as a test application(standard java app).

To solve my issue I set the class I need to serialize to implement serializable, and this is where the weird behavior starts. From the test application, with this change, I am now able to serialize the class to a binary array, yet in the app engine project I keep getting a class not serializable error. To get round this I implemented the serializing method as part of the class I need to serialize. Once again this works well from the test project, but when I try to run it from the app engine project (copy and pasting the code to make sure there are no changes), I am getting a "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" error. It is also worth noting that the ide itself does not show any errors in the code.

Anyone ever ran into something similar and has a clue what to do, as I honestly have no idea what to check, and I can't seem to find any solutions to such an issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is it in a separate .jar file? Have you included it in your project?

Have you tried cleaning your project then trying to build it?

Comment: At this point no, its set as a project link. Yes I tried cleaning and building again (also tried unlinking the projects and relinking them again).